# How to retrieve month, month day, weekday and hour from DateTime string?

Tags: python, datetime

I have this code to generate date and time objects in ISO format:

```
from date time import datetime

datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m.%dT%H:%M")
```

> '2018-09-05T14:09'

How can I retrieve `month`, `month day`, `weekday` and `hour` from this string without using regex?

Comment: Is it a requirement to get this information from the string, or can you get it from the actual object? If its the latter then it is trivially easy i.e. `datetime.now().month`

Comment: See the documentation for `strptime()`.

Comment: @stybl: No, it should be obtained from a string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 import datetime

string = "19 Nov 2015  18:45:00.000"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%d %b %Y  %H:%M:%S.%f")
print(date.year)

print(date.month)

print(date.day)

print(date.hour)

print(date.minute)

print(date.second)
```

https://onlinegdb.com/S1KDCmKzN

Comment: `datetime.datetime.today().weekday()`